# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) unexpectedly happen only for firebase swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2, swift3

I had Firebase set up and working properly, then without making any changes it stopped being able to save or retrieve info from the database. I also started receiving this in the console with no further info.

```
2016-08-07 21:42:30.097 [2554:1348268] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
```

The memory keeps going up until it crashes from memory issue, I assume it has to do with the network request continuing until it recieves some type of callback.

As a temp fix to see if I could solve the issue I set transport security to allow arbitrary loads and I also tried adding the below to my Plist file with no success:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
   <dict>
    <key>YOUR_HOST.COM</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>1.0</string>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</dict>
```

I tried other network requests that did work so it is isolated to Firebase. This is a swift 3.0 project using xcode 8 beta 4 but as I mentioned before, everything was working fine earlier.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This also applies to my project but only when using firebase in the share extension. Using firebase in the app itself works flawlessly. I'm not experiencing the memory issue, just the failed SSL handshake.